# Could not subscribe to salesforce with API_VERSION 48 from restforce

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, salesforce, restforce

I am currently subscribing for 2 topics one for Account and another for Contacts. I am successfully able to subscribe to both topics with api_version 26 (default version used by restforce), but I don't get events for delete actions with this api_version.
Gems used:

```
gem 'cookiejar', git: 'https://github.com/MissionCapital/cookiejar.git'  
gem 'faye', '0.8.9'
gem 'restforce', '~> 4.2.2'
```

code:

```
@client = Restforce.new(username: ENV['SF_USERNAME'],
                        password: ENV['SF_PASSWORD'],
                        security_token: ENV['SF_SECURITY_TOKEN'],
                        client_id: ENV['SF_CLIENT_ID'],
                        client_secret: ENV['SF_SECRET_ID'])
```

PushTopic

```
@client.create!('PushTopic',
                                ApiVersion: '48.0',
                                Name: ENV['CONTACT_PUSH_TOPIC_NAME'],
                                Description: 'all contact records',
                                NotifyForOperations: 'All',
                                NotifyForFields: 'All',
                                Query: 'select Id, FirstName, LastName, Title, Email, Phone, MobilePhone, OtherPhone, AccountId, OwnerId, IsDeleted from Contact')
```

This results in the client being in version with `26.0` of the salesforce.

NOW, change to salesforce api_verison `48.0`

```
@client = Restforce.new(username: ENV['SF_USERNAME'],
                        password: ENV['SF_PASSWORD'],
                        security_token: ENV['SF_SECURITY_TOKEN'],
                        client_id: ENV['SF_CLIENT_ID'],
                        client_secret: ENV['SF_SECRET_ID'],
                        api_version: '48.0')
```

Pushtopic

```
@client.create!('PushTopic',
                                ApiVersion: '48.0',
                                Name: ENV['CONTACT_PUSH_TOPIC_NAME'],
                                Description: 'all contact records',
                                NotifyForOperationCreate: 'true',
                                NotifyForOperationUpdate: 'true',
                                NotifyForOperationDelete: 'true',
                                NotifyForOperationUndelete: 'true',
                                NotifyForFields: 'All',
                                Query: 'select Id, FirstName, LastName, Title, Email, Phone, MobilePhone, AccountId, OwnerId, IsDeleted from Contact')
```

For this client, it doesn't receive any events. not for any actions (create, update, or delete).

Issue filed on Github. link: https://github.com/restforce/restforce/issues/537

Answer (score 2):

Answer: We need to use `replay` for working with higher versions. It doesn't subscribe without replay.

```
 EM.run do
   @client.subscription "/topic/topicName", replay: -2  do |message|
     puts message["sobject"]
  end
 end
```

Comment: Note that with replay = -2 you'll replay all stored messages on re-subsciption. More info https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/using_streaming_api_durability.htm